# Which Fresnel coefficients should be used at normal incidence?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, reflection

There are two sets of Fresnel coefficients depending on the polarisation of the incident light. At normal incidence these equations converge except there is a phase factor of $\pm1$ For the reflection coefficient

$r = \pm \frac{n_1 - n_2}{n_1 + n_2} $

For a normal incidence EM wave, how do you decide between these factors?

**Edit - Additional Information**

The reason I came to this question is that I was trying to derive the reflection equations for both electric fields and magnetic fields at an interface. At normal incidence, the boundary conditions for both the **E** and **H** fields are the same (as far as I can tell) but one must lag behind the other by $\pm \pi/2$. I can't figure out which one I should choose, and it seems to be an equivalent question to my original question.

Comment: Use the Fresnel coefficient for the polarisation of the light for which you want to do the calculation.

Comment: Isn’t it ambiguous at normal incidence?

Answer (score 2):

Circular polarization flips its handiness on normal incident reflection, because the convention for handiness (and thus phases) are to "look" against the beam direction, not to look into a fixed lab direction.

The difference in sign for s and p at normal incidence is due to your degenerate choice of "scattering plane", since there are two ways to flip your reference direction.

Answer (score 1):

The minus sign is due to the different conventions for field direction for s and p waves. There is a conventional sign difference between the incoming and the outgoing wave for p-polarisation. You should use the plus sign for s and the minus sign for p to take this into account.

Comment: Right, but don't these two conventions disagree with each other at normal incidence? The main example I can think of is standing waves. If $r=-1$ then the node is at the surface, if $r=1$ the antinode is at the surface. Am I incorrect?

Comment: @user668074 It is the difference for reflection at an open end or at a fixed and of a rope. In optics, the phase depends on the optical density, $n$.

Comment: @Pieter I agree, but isn't this built into the Fresnel equations through $n_1 - n_2$? So whether you go from a rare medium into a dense medium is already accounted for.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed at normal incidence, P and S polarizations are not well defined, because $\vec{k}\times\vec{n} = 0$ (where $\vec{n}$ is the normal of the plane). I would argue that in the extreme case of total reflection - such as in a mirror, you should use the plus sign. Here's why:

From wave theory, we know that the reflection coefficient of a wave propagating into a medium with different impedance is:

$$r = \frac{z_1 - z_2 }{z_1 + z_2}$$

See [Derivation in David Morin's wave book (draft), sections 4.2.2 and 4.3](https://scholar.harvard.edu/files/david-morin/files/waves_transverse.pdf). This is exactly the **S polarized Fresnel coefficient  ($r_s$)** you get when you *don't* set $\mu_1 = \mu_2 = \mu_0$, see also [this derivation of Fresnel coefficients](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/University_Physics/Book%3A_Introductory_Physics_-_Building_Models_to_Describe_Our_World_(Martin_Neary_Rinaldo_and_Woodman)/14%3A_Waves/14.03%3A_Waves_on_a_Rope). This is why it makes sense to take the plus sign as the normal incidence reflection coefficient.

Answer (score 0):

I too had this question and after staring on the diagram in my book and on the replies here I finally have an answer.

It boils down to what equation you use to describe the reflected wave. We work in complex representation, so your incident wave is:
$$\tilde {\vec E}=\tilde {\vec E_0}e^{-i(\vec k \cdot \vec r-\omega \cdot t)}$$
I will now use the convention in my book to describe normal incidence (see attached image).

S-polarized incident wave is
$$\tilde {\vec E_{0s}}=(0,E_y,0)$$
P-polarized incident wave
$$\tilde {\vec E_{0p}}=(E_x,0,0)$$

S-polarized reflected wave:

$$\tilde {\vec E_{0sr}}=(0,E_{yr},0)$$

P-polarized reflected wave
$$\tilde {\vec E_{0pr}}=(-E_{xr},0,0)$$

The sign of the vectors is + if they point along the x axis and - if against.
The books gives the coefficients: $r_s=\frac{n_1-n_2}{n_1+n_2}$ and $r_p=-\frac{n_1-n_2}{n_1+n_2}$.

If we multiply the complex amplitude by the corresponding coefficient, we get positive result in both cases.
$$\tilde {\vec E_{0r}}=r \cdot \tilde {\vec E_{0}}$$
$$E_{yr}=\frac{n_1-n_2}{n_1+n_2}E_y$$
$$E_{xr}=-\frac{n_1-n_2}{n_1+n_2}\cdot (-E_x)=\frac{n_1-n_2}{n_1+n_2}\cdot E_x$$

In other words the choice of s and p polarization influences which direction is positive and which is negative for your reflected wave. There is many of these convention choices in physics. Just choose one and stick with it.

[image: Image for derivation of Fresnel equations (Malý, P. (2013) Optika. Prague, Czech Republic: Charles University/Karolinum.)]