# Sign of reflection coefficient $E_r/E_i$ at normal incidence!

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, reflection, conventions, geometric-optics

At normal incidence the plane of incidence is not defined! So how do we will understand that whether the reflection coefficient is positive or negative; because  according to frensel equation for **E** perpendicular to the plane of incidence and for **E** parallel to the plane of incidence have different singns(*i.e. positive or negative*) for reflection coefficient; but as for the case of normal incidence there is no specific plane of incidence ; So what sign should I choose?
*Reference: * "Optics" by Hetch

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Phase difference in reflection coefficient between S and P polarisation at normal incidence?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/489229/phase-difference-in-reflection-coefficient-between-s-and-p-polarisation-at-norma) and https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/430708/which-fresnel-coefficients-should-be-used-at-normal-incidence?rq=1

Comment: @RobJeffries but in wikipedia it is said that this is a paradox! So is there any solution ?

Comment: If $n_1<n_2$ then $E_i$ and $E_r$ point in opposite directions.

Comment: @RobJeffries but why? this is the case when Electric field is perpendicular to the plane of incidence!

Comment: Because physics. Draw a diagram, use the boundary conditions, that's how it works. I can't really see the problem. The relationship between $E_i$ and $E_r$ is trivial to find at normal incidence.

Comment: @RobJeffries dude I have done this and came up with both of the results!

Comment: What do you mean both of the results? There is only one result, which is that $E_i$ and $E_r$ are in opposite directions when $n_2 > n_1$. If you have found otherwise, I suggest you carefully look at your diagram and which way you defined $E_r$ on that diagram.

Comment: i.e. if I start with a diagram that defines $E_r$ in the same direction as $E_i$, I get $r = (n_1-n_2)/(n_1+n_2)$ and if I start by defining them in opposite directions I get $r = (n_2-n_1)/(n_1+n_2)$. That initial definition is essentially what is going on with the Fresnel equations.

Comment: @RobJeffries thanks dude for your time! Now I got it now actually the problem was understanding the picture! Thanks a lot!